# UIImagePickerController and pre-selected photo

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

I am working with a UIImagePickerController. A page in my app can display a photo. When it does, I would like to be able to let the user edit that photo. I see how UIImagePickerController allows you to select a photo from all the photos available. Is there a way I can give the UIImagePickerController a specific photo and instruct it to let the user begin editing that photo? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this can't be done with `UIImagePickerController`. What editing do you wish to allow on the photo? If it is just cropping then put it in a UIScrollView and let the user zoom and pan. Crop the image based on what they do. If you want more editing capabilities then you have more work. Look into 3rd party solutions such as the Aviary SDK.

Comment: Thanks. I want to let them do what iPad users have come to expect. I'll just have to wait and see what they tell me.

Comment: And is it possible with UIImagePickerController to access the PhotoLibrary, by directly opening the pre-selected photo and that the user can delete it (but within the PhotoLibrary application) ???